# How to redraw the UI in a child window?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm creating a child window that moves the UI with a scrollbar.
The UI refers to the position of the scroll bar and runs MoveWindow().

I expect the UI to be redrawn when I run the UpdateWindow(), but an afterimage remains.
What should be the correct way to redraw?

Parent Window

```
BOOL CScrollWindowDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    InnerWindow* inwin = new InnerWindow();
    inwin->Create(NULL, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL, CRect(50, 50, 600, 450), this, NULL);
    inwin->Init();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Child Window

```
#pragma once
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <memory>

class InnerWindow : public CWnd
{
public:
    InnerWindow();
    ~InnerWindow();

    void Init();

protected:
    afx_msg void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
    std::unique_ptr<CStatic> m_label;
    SCROLLINFO m_scrollinfo;
};
```

```
void InnerWindow::Init()
{
    m_label = std::unique_ptr<CStatic>(new CStatic());
    m_label->Create(L"Sample My Label", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(10, 10, 300, 30), this, 0x1010);
    m_label->ShowWindow(TRUE);

    ZeroMemory(&m_scrollinfo, sizeof(m_scrollinfo));
    m_scrollinfo.fMask = SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL | SIF_ALL;
    m_scrollinfo.nMin = 0;
    m_scrollinfo.nMax = 400 * 2;
    m_scrollinfo.nPage = 400;
    m_scrollinfo.nPos = 0;
    SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &m_scrollinfo);
}

void InnerWindow::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    if (pScrollBar == nullptr)
    {
        switch (nSBCode)
        {
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            m_label->MoveWindow(10, 10 + nPos, 290, 20);
            m_scrollinfo.nPos = nPos;
            SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &m_scrollinfo);

            Invalidate();
            UpdateWindow();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    CWnd::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you checking `pScrollBar` for nullptr?

Comment: Added to distinguish between other CScrollBar controls(not null) and window scrollbars(null). This example is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify window class for your `InnerWindow` here:

```
inwin->Create(NULL, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL, CRect(50, 50, 600, 450), this, NULL);
```

Nobody paints that window, or erases its background.

If you don't have any special needs for that window, I would just use `STATIC`:

```
inwin->Create(L"STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL, CRect(50, 50, 600, 450), this, NULL);
```

Comment: @Evan.Titer - my suggestion still stands - use `STATIC` for the window class

Comment: When I set it to STATIC, the scroll bar stopped working. I want to move the UI with a scroll bar.

Comment: @Evan.Titer - right, "STATIC" blocks everything. You can see how it works if you use L"BUTTON" class, but you really should define your own.

Comment: Success! I set WNDCLASS to create method.